# How to save a file from a URL in Parse.com using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, parse-platform

I know the syntax for saving files in Parse.com (https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#files-classes), but now I have a URL instead of a local file - http://graph.facebook.com/{FacebookID}/picture, how can I save it in Parse? Thanks!

Comment: You don't.  Well, you can download it first.  Or, just store a URL on Parse.

Comment: the key "profilepic" is a file type not string type in my Parse setting. download to where? local storage of the mobile? by how?  thx. @Fosco

Comment: That's a separate question, unrelated to Parse.  You can't create/save a Parse File with the contents of a remote file, only data you have locally (like a base 64 encoded string, or a byte array, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create/save a Parse File with the contents of a remote file, only data you have locally (like a base 64 encoded string, or a byte array, etc.)

See the Parse File (JavaScript) docs here: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#files